# sqlplus connection error on crontab but works directly

Tags: oracle, shell, cron, sqlplus

I'm using following script to create text file with oracle query output. The script work fine when I try it manually. But when I place it to crontab it is permanently fail to get the connection. Is there any restriction to access sqlplus through automation?

```
rm /export/home/oracle/out.csv 
INC=0


while : ; do    

INC=$(($INC+1))
if [[ "$INC" -eq 10 ]]; then
    echo "Exit after multiple failed attempt to connect to the DB."
    break
fi

sqlplus -s username/password@hostname.com:1552/servicename << EOF
set pagesize 10000

set feedback off
set heading off
set echo off

spool /export/home/oracle/out.csv 
SET LINESIZE 10000
SET PAGESIZE 50
SELECT TRIM(COUNT(*)) FROM users;
SPOOL OFF
EXIT;
EOF

[[ -f "/export/home/oracle/out.csv" ]] && break
echo "Failed to connect to DB and retrying."
sleep 5

done
```

Comment: Are you sure that sqlplus can be found? And which shell is used for this cron job?

Comment: sqlplus is there. The same script work fine when I run through console "./report.sh" but only issue in crontab. Same user used for both.

Comment: Could you add the content of the crontab to your question?

Comment: your PATH env variable may be different when running from crontab, does it work when you specify full path to sqlplus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cron utility uses "/bin/sh" as default shell, so you need to setup Oracle environment accordingly.

You may:

1.- Have a configuration file containing the necessary variables. (*)

2.- Hard code the necessary Oracle environment variables in your script.

In your case:

For solution "1", you can create **$HOME/profile.12cR2** file with the following content:

```
export ORACLE_BASE=/oraclebin/app/oracle/product/databaseR2/base
export ORACLE_HOME=/oraclebin/app/oracle/product/databaseR2/12cR2

export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib
export CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib

export ORACLE_SID=db02

export EDITOR=vi
```

And update your script as follows:

```
. $HOME/profile.12cR2

rm /export/home/oracle/out.csv 
INC=0


while : ; do    

INC=$(($INC+1))
if [[ "$INC" -eq 10 ]]; then
    echo "Exit after multiple failed attempt to connect to the DB."
    break
fi
...
```

(*) Update this configuration file according your Oracle database infrastructure.

Comment: Brilliant answer. The first block with environment variables fix the issue. Thank you