# Why oracle database sync job fails but connection using SQL client succeeds

Tags: sql, oracle, cron

We could even run queries successfully in any SQL client but cron on the same script fails.
What could be all possible reasons for it?

Comment: How are the scripts executed by cron? If you use SQL*Plus make sure the relevant environment variables are set, since cron usually runs within a minimal environment.

Answer (score 0):

In our cron jobs, we use the following commands at the beginning of our `.sh` files:

```
export TMP=/tmp
export TMPDIR=$TMP

export ORACLE_HOSTNAME=sample.com
export ORACLE_UNQNAME=sample_service
export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1
export ORACLE_SID=sample_service

export PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib
export CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib

export TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin
```

As pointed out by [Marco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2198584/marco-baldelli), these are our environment variables we exported in order for our sql scripts to run when we use cron. Try adding them to your scripts, and make sure to change the paths as needed.

Also, this answer on a similar question may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33213703/5399719